# Running (Perl's) CPAN in OS X: error "Can't open perl script –MCPAN"

Tags: terminal, development

All the instructions I can find for running CPAN on Mac OS X (eg. [1](http://triopter.com/archive/how-to-install-perl-modules-on-mac-os-x-in-4-easy-steps/), [2](http://triopter.com/archive/how-to-install-perl-modules-on-mac-os-x-in-4-easy-steps/) & [3](http://perl.about.com/od/packagesmodules/qt/perlcpan.htm)) say to start by running this command in terminal:

```
sudo perl –MCPAN –e shell
```

However when I do so I get this error:

```
Can't open perl script "–MCPAN": No such file or directory
```

Why is this and how can I fix it? I'm running Lion (10.7.3) and have installed XCode 4.2.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

sudo cpan

cpan is an executable that comes installed in OS X (or installs with Xcode).